# Is it possible to capture/find the dimensions of a flash movie as it loads into a webpage?

Tags: javascript, flash, actionscript-3

I have a cms where my client loads banner ads from their clients. They don't know the dimensions or don't want to enter them when they upload the banners. Is it possible to capture the dimensions to set the object attributes as we grab the movies from the db to display in the page?
I read that the movie dimensions are available in the loaderinfo object, but this is a AS3 object right? Are AS3 objects available outside the flash movie? Can I access the loaderobject via javascript?
The Flash movies we're trying to load are not ours, we don't have access to the flas or anything like that so we can't edit anything to do with the movies themselves.

Answer (score 0):

This might help

http://blog.codefidelity.com/?p=14

I think you can even use jquery with more ease

Try something like $("object").height() and $("object").width(); if you have just one object tag for flash .

Comment: I couldn't get either example to work. The codefidelity example can be seen here, http://www.entropyid.com/test.html - gives huge width and height. And a jQuery example can be seen here, http://www.entropyid.com/test2.html, again width and height are not correct. width and height should both be 187px. Am I missing something really obvious?

Answer (score 0):

You can also do something server side, if you want the size to be stored 100% accurately without user input.

This python script, for example, will output the compression type, version, size (compressed or uncompressed) and the dimensions.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import bitstring
import zlib

swf_file = file("test.swf", "rb")
swf = swf_file.read()
swf_file.close()

bits = bitstring.ConstBitStream(filename="test.swf")
type = "".join(map(chr, bits.readlist('uint:8, uint:8, uint:8')))
print "Compression:         ", type
print "Version:             ", bits.read('uint:8')
swf_length = bits.read('uintle:32')
if type == 'CWS':
    print "Compressed Size:     ", swf_length
    f = zlib.decompress(bits.bytes[8:], zlib.MAX_WBITS)
    bits = bitstring.ConstBitStream(bytes=f, length=swf_length * 8 - 64)
else:
    print "Uncompressed Size:   ", swf_length
nbits = bits.read('uint:5')
xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax = bits.readlist('uint:{size}, uint:{size}, uint:{size}, uint:{size}'.format(size = nbits))
print "Dimensions:           {x}x{y}".format(x = (xmax - xmin) / 20, y = (ymax - ymin) / 20)
```

Example Output:

```
Compression:          CWS
Version:              10
Compressed Size:      166608
Dimensions:           200x100
```